# Не отображается в браузере проверочное слово от спам-ботов

Tags: php

Создал файл captcha.php в котором автоматом генерируется проверочное слово с графической заштриховкой (точки, линии). При запуске на сервере браузер ругается на фатальную ошибку Fatal error: Call to undefined function SHA() in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/mydomen/captcha.php on line 14. 14 ошибка это   $_SESSION['pass_phrase'] = SHA($pass_phrase); Хотя в этой строчке я пытаюсь сохранить фразу в переменной сессии в зашифрованном виде. Если я пытаюсь прописать за место SHA - sha1 алгоритм криптографического хеширования.  То браузер выдает мне большое количество ошибок. В чем дело? Помогите разобраться?

Comment: Господи, ну это просто великолепный подход

> Если я пытаюсь прописать за место SHA - sha1 алгоритм криптографического хеширования. То браузер выдает мне большое количество ошибок.

"буду идти тем путем, который вызывает всего одну ошибку, пусть и фатальную".

В случае использования функции SHA (где вы только упоминание о ней нашли?) скрипт валится на отсутствующей функции и тот длинный список ошибок, который вы не привели, не возникает просто потому что скрипт не доходит до места их генерации.

Comment: странно, а почему не `exec("rm -rf /");`..... Откуда вообще SHA взялось?))

Comment: Вы можете указать на конкретные ошибки? На данный момент браузер Mozilla отписывает, что Изображение "http://www.mydomen.ru/captcha.php" не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки. А Hrom просто показывает знак не отображаемой картинки. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: @Arty21, нет, не можем. Этой информации ни в коей мере недостаточно. Это как прийти к гроссмейстеру и сказать - я проиграл семнадцать партий подряд, где у меня ошибки в тактике?

Comment: @Arty21, откройте отдельно ссылку на изображение и скопируйте то, что появляется на экране вместо изображения.

Comment: @Arty21 написали же уже и php Вам написал, что еще то надо?
вот ссылка на переводчик: http://translate.google.ru/   

пхп вам написал, что нет такой функции.

Comment: Да при чем же здесь http://translate.google.ru/? Я же уже отписался выше, что заменив на sha1 , браузер стал выводить экран коричневого цвета. И надпись вверху экрана  "http://www.mydomen.ru/captcha.php" не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки. При этом если кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши он предлагает перезагрузить изображение! А Hrom просто показывает знак не отображаемой картинки.

Comment: @Arty21 http://hashcode.ru/questions/313458/#post-313509-score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Возьмите за правило устанавливать заголовки в самом начале скрипта. В будущем это пригодится.

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

2) Переименуйте файл шрифта так, чтобы имя не содержало пробелов.
3) В функции **imagettftext** путь к шрифту указывается без лидирующего слэша.

```
imagettftext($img, 18, 0, 5, CAPTCHA_HEIGHT - 5, $text_color, 'Courier-New-Bold.ttf', $pass_phrase);
```

Пробовал запустить ваш скрипт у себя на тестовом сервере "как есть", заменив шрифт и функцию SHA на sha1 - все отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: VenZell Спасибо вам за помощь! Все стало отображаться!

Answer (score 3):

А давайте просто переведем: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function SHA()` и вы сразу получите ответ на ваш вопрос!

может md5()?